# "PALETTE MANAGER" function can´t be showed when right click ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, ide

I have tried to add the JCalendar option to the Eclipse IDE but when I right click on the palette section, when I right click I only get the "Layout" and "Settings" options.

I tried changin the configurations of Eclipse IDES

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 2022-9 have this issue, to solve this problem what you have to do is to download previous versions, like 2022-6 or earlier, with the corresponding WindowsBuilder, in my case I downloaded 1.9.8.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also installed `WindowBuilder Nightly Build`?
If so, uninstall it. Only install the stable WindowBuilder plugin. That's what worked for me.